# Having Trouble Getting Starts with ios-charts library

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I am having trouble utilizing this [ios-chart library](https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts). I have successfully added it to my project using `CocoaPods` but my question is now what?

First step I am stuck at is -- how do I add a Chart Object to a ViewController in my Storyboard? In the `Object Library`, I dont see anything with the name `Chart` (screenshot below).

[image]

How do I get started? They have an [example project but it's in Objective-C](https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts/tree/master/ChartsDemo) but I cannot tell how to pull a Chart object into my ViewController and only then I can start coding/configuring it right?

Comment: You aren't going to find charts in the library, you need to search in the file explorer.

Comment: @Abizern thanks. I find it under framework in my Pods but how do I pull it into my Storyboard ViewController? or should I just add a `View` to the Storyboard and have to assign a class to it?

Comment: What do the examples do?

Comment: try following this tutorial: http://www.appcoda.com/ios-charts-api-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Drag-drop a view first to your storyboard, and then assign a class to the view. In that class, import the charts framework.

Comment: What do you mean by a "View list" here?

Comment: Drag and drop an UIView from object library.